# Youtrack. change time tracking by workflow

Tags: workflow, jetbrains-ide, youtrack, time-tracking

Can I somehow in spend time include only development type of time tracking?

For example, in time tracking for issue we have `3h` for testing, `7h` for dev, `2h` management, so in spend time show only `7h`, not `1d 4h`.

And in estimation the same that include only development?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no possibility to display only development time in 'spent time'/'estimation' field.

However, you can create a separate field to store development spent time there. You'll need an on-change workflow rule (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/standalone/Workflow-Tutorial.html#tutorial-create-on-change-rule) which will trigger on work items adding (ctx.issue.workItems.added.isNotEmpty()), check if work item type is 'development' (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/standalone/v1-IssueWorkItem.html), and (if yes) will update this separate custom field respectively.

Hope it helps.